# How to draw my graph in latex?

Tags: graphics, graphs

[image: Graph 1]

I would need to create the graph using LaTex. I have no idea how to do it. Could you help? Thanks

Comment: You can use TikZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SX!

It is not very hard with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}%
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-node}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-3)(4.5,3.2)
\everypsbox{\scriptsize}
\psset{arrowinset=0.15, linejoin, arrows= <->, linecolor=SteelBlue, labelsep=3pt}
\psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none](0,0)(-4,-3)(4.5,3)
\psline(-3.8,3)(3.8,-3)
% Define empty nodes for texts placement
    \pnodes(-4,0){regA}(4.5,0){regZ}(0,2.1){col}(0,-2.5){incol}(-3.8,3){for}(3.8,-3){infor}
 % Texts placement
 \uput[ur](regA){\enspace italiano regionale A}
 \uput[ul](regZ){italiano regionale Z\enspace }
 \uput[ur](regA){\enspace italiano regionale A}
 \uput[l](col){italiano colto}
 \uput[l](incol){italiano incolto}
 \uput{4ex}[-30](for){\Shortstack{italiano scritto\\ formale}}
 \uput{3.5ex}[u](infor){\Shortstack{italiano scritto\\ informale}}
 \uput[r](0, 1.5){DIASTRATIA}
 \uput{1.5ex}[d](-2, 0){DIATOPIA}
 \uput[r](0.6, -1.9){DIAFASIA}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]